# Subdirectory naming convention

Tags: file-management

I have a big directory of data/code that I am reorganizing following [these useful guidelines](http://software-carpentry.org/4_0/data/mgmt/). As a result I will create a lot of subdirectories. I would like to standardize the subdirectory names with a consistent naming convention that would be compatible with any operating system. Which of the following is more 'standard'? Or suggest another. (I am avoiding spaces).

1. subdirectory_name
2. subdirectoryName
3. SubdirectoryName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no standard other than the one *you* decide on.** Currently popular operating systems support all these names equally well, and the organization of your files is your own choice.

In terms of compatibility, all three versions are fine, and **there is no reason to avoid spaces, either.** In fact, when Windows introduced long file name support in **1995** (upper/lower case and spaces supported, with full Unicode support added in 1996), Unix already had the same for over twenty years (Wikipedia lists V6FS from year **1972**).  To remind, we're currently in year 2012.

*(...Unless you are going to use MS-DOS or VMS as your primary OS, in which case [this comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) may be interesting.)*

Comment: Do you think all 3 are equally easy to scan when reading a long list of subdirectories?